# How do I figure out what fields to mark as transient when tryhing to use Gson's toJson method?

Tags: java, json, serialization, gson, transient

I'm using Gson 2.8.1.  I have this code

```
        Object o = session.getSecurityContext();
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String serialized = gson.toJson(o);
```

It results in this stack overflow error.

```
15:45:47,784 ERROR [io.undertow.request] (default task-58) UT005023: Exception handling request to /ebook/WEB-INF/views/registration/studentConfirm.jsp: java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at sun.util.locale.provider.DateFormatSymbolsProviderImpl.getInstance(DateFormatSymbolsProviderImpl.java:85)
    at java.text.DateFormatSymbols.getProviderInstance(DateFormatSymbols.java:359)
    at java.text.DateFormatSymbols.getInstance(DateFormatSymbols.java:335)
    at java.util.Calendar.getDisplayName(Calendar.java:2110)
    at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.subFormat(SimpleDateFormat.java:1125)
    at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.format(SimpleDateFormat.java:966)
    at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.format(SimpleDateFormat.java:936)
    at java.text.DateFormat.format(DateFormat.java:345)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.DateTypeAdapter.write(DateTypeAdapter.java:83)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.DateTypeAdapter.write(DateTypeAdapter.java:41)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$26$1.write(TypeAdapters.java:586)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$26$1.write(TypeAdapters.java:579)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:69)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:125)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:243)
    at com.google.gson.Gson$FutureTypeAdapter.write(Gson.java:976)
```

Per other answers, if I mark the circular reference that is causing this as "transient," this will supposedly go away, but how do I figure that out programmatically?  I have looked at the object in question and it is not obvious to me through code checking what the circular reference is.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the GSON User Guide (https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide), you mark a field as *transient* when it shouldn't be serialized.

Ideally, you would know beforehand which references are circular, and simply avoid serializing them. On the other hand, you might not know this information, so having some way of constructing a complex object from less complex parts is sometimes beneficial.

For example, if I am trying to serialize a complicated `Date` object, it might be better to simply add a constructor like the following:

```
public Date(double ms) {
  // create new Date from milliseconds from the epoch
}
```

then, where you would serialize a `Date` object, convert it to milliseconds and serialize the `double` instead. You can use type interceptors to perform this kind of conditional serialization based on type.

Serialization has been a problem since the dawn of the Java language. You can't simply stick any object into a serialization mechanism and expect that it's magically going to work, unfortunately. That said, many objects *will* work with GSON, provided you break them down a bit.

When all else fails, trial and error (like you've just seen) works, too. When I was working with GSON serialization/deserialization and I encountered an object I hadn't serialized before, I would first write a unit test for it, to make sure that serialization and deserialization works the way I expect, before putting it in production code.

Comment: Maybe its because I'm new to GSON, but I don't udnerstand how I figure out what field is transient based on your answer.  "Trial and error" is what I've been doing and it hasn't really led me anywhere.

Comment: A field needs to be transient if it can't be serialized. Typically, this is something that is more complex than a simple object with a few data values (e.g. your example of a security context).